# UITableView memory management

Tags: iphone

can someone please clarify this: when a table cell scrolls off the screen, does it still reside in memory? The reason why I am asking this is, I had to use a tableview that has to handle too many cells. 
when you scroll the table up, it loads next set of visible cells. At this point, i want to make sure , that all the cells thats been scrolled off, wont be added as a heap slowing the performance. Thanks,

Comment: It would be great if you could show us what you're doing in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 2):

If you queue the cells then each cell, as soon as it disappears from the screen (that is, it is scrolled up or down), is re-used for other new cells entering in the screen.
This means that if your screen can show no more than 7 cells at the moment, the memory taken for cell allocations will not be higher than the one needed for exactly 7 of them.
The advantage of this approach is memory saving but also performance improvement as you don't need to alloc/init the cells each time.

Of course this is valid if you appropriately autorelease cells when created, if you use the same queue identifier and of course it is independent on your way to manage the data you will insert in the queue (images, strings, ...)

Comment: First off, thanks for your reply. I have implemented as you mentioned. and I am auto releasing it as well. But as i scroll the table up , I am seeing the total memory summing up in the performance tool. i.e I observed 1.5MB when its showing 8 cells, and as i scroll up to show the next 8 cells, the total memory goes to aroung 2.5MB. am I missing something here? the ideal case should be around 1.5MB all the time- rt?

Comment: What I suggest you is to use the Instruments tool/Leaks-Memory allocation and mark heapshots in this way: you start your app, navigate to the table and mark heapshot; then you do some scroll (a few rows), mark another heapshot; then you scroll back to the initial position, and mark another heapshot. You may expect an increase between the first two heapshots (visible cells + one queued cell at least), but then when you go to the last heapshot you shouldn't see any extra difference with the second. If you have negligible difference, then you are leaking something with your cells content.